# How to display user_meta from form?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I have a form on my website where a user can choose their location from a dropdown list (eg, France, Italy, Germany, etc) when they are writing a post. This is the code used for the LOCATION field:

```
<?php   

        $locs = get_user_meta($uid, 'user_location', true);

        echo PricerrTheme_get_categories("job_location",  
        !isset($_POST['job_location_cat']) ?  $locs : htmlspecialchars($_POST['job_location_cat'])
        , __('Select Location','PricerrTheme'), "do_input"); ?>
```

I would like the chosen location to be displayed on the user's profile page so people know which country they are from. On this page, I've added this code:

```
<?php echo $locs = get_user_meta($uid, 'user_location', true); ?>
```

Unfortunately this only displays the ID number of the location (ie, "3") instead of by name (ie, "Germany"). What do I need to add or remove from this code to get the name of the location to display?

Comment: I would define an array of locations to use it both in loop and displaying of location.

Comment: Any success? I would still prefer more broader (non-wp specific) approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can just make an array

```
$locations = array(
      0 => 'France',
      1 => 'Italy',
      2 => 'Germany');
```

to both use it both places (im sorry if there is an different aproach for WP, just for the idea)

```
<?php foreach ($locations as $location) : ?>
//do smth
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

and echo the result as text

```
<?php 
    $locs_id = get_user_meta($uid, 'user_location', true);
    echo $locations[$locs_id];
?>
```